# Advanced Methods for finding best predictionset

Tags: predictive-models, prediction

I have a dataset where the number of possible predictors number ~ 2000. This is nutrition data of macro and micro nutrients from diet.  Many of these are going to be highly correlated.

The number of observations are only ~300. My understanding is there are some new methods that can handle the correlation structure between these variables. I want to find the best subset of predictors for a given outcome. I have many different outcomes, so the predictor set will be different for each outcome.

Note: I am not talking about forward/backward etc... selection procedures with linear regression.

I know this is broad, but I'm actually just looking for the "names" of said methods so I can read about them. This is more a question of I don't really know the best search terms for what I am trying to find.

EDIT: For example I was looking at Structural Equation Modeling

Comment: The first name that comes to (my) mind is lasso and then ridge.  Then random forests and gradient boosting.  Finally there is auto-encoding, but that is probably not useful on your data set as you don't have 'enough' variables or data. .

Comment: Perfect, that was something a colleague mentioned a while back and I couldn't remember what was said.